# How to round this image logo using CSS,

Tags: css

I've applied this code to my image, but it doesn't turn to a Rounded shape,

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  height: 41px;
  margin: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stye.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar background">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x70" alt="logo"></div>
      <li>
        <a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#about"></a>About</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#services"></a>Services</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact-Us"></a>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="right-nav">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
      <button class="btn btn-sm">Search</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

I've tried this code too:

```
width:23% (of the parent element)
border-radius:35px;
```

I've tried 1:1 ratio but it damaged the picture quality.

Comment: i apologize for that, please review now. Thanks

Comment: The image is in oval shape, i want it in proper circle

Comment: Alright
I'll put div outside from list :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a element thats not a 1:1 ratio you will not get a 'perfect' circle. try making the height and width the same if that is what you want.

Comment: I set the height and width the same value. That disturbs the picture quality.

Comment: use object-fit: cover;

Answer (score 0):

based on your first set of code, you need to add:

width: 41px;

that should make your border a circle

this does mess up your image and you could use `object-fit: cover;`
this code keeps the image its aspect ratio and fills the given dimension